# How is the brain kickstarted during development

Tags: brain, development, mammals

The brain is a complicated beast, that operates (generally) by electrical activity. During development, all cells originate from the a single "cell": the zygote.

At some point during development, the cells will begin to form into the specialised cells of the brain. But how does the brain activity start?

Is there some process that gets things going, akin to jump starting a car? Specifically, I'm referring to the mammalian (and more specifically human) brain.

Comment: Given the right set of molecular machinery, neurons can start firing spontaneously. No kickstart needed.

Comment: If nothing else, touch, temperature and other sensory neurons will start firing in response to stimuli detected by the embryo, which will start firing impulses into the brain.